# mysql_query returns nothing, but works manually with åæø

Tags: php, mysql, utf-8

I have some problems with a query in MySQL.

I use the character set UTF-8, which I have set in the header.

the connection to MySQL is also set with

mysql_set_charset("utf8", $conn);

My database uses utf8_general_ci

When i echo my query and manually insert it inside phpMyAdmin it works fine.

e.g.

```
SELECT `project_number` FROM `1` WHERE `project_name`='æøå'
```

But when I insert this query

```
$row = mysql_fetch_assoc(mysql_query("SELECT `project_number` FROM `$user_id` WHERE `project_name`='$project_name'"));
$project_number = $row['project_number'];
```

project_number returns nothing, when i use special characters like æøå, but works when I don't use æøå.

Comment: Do you really have a table called `1`? Why don't you have a single `projects` table including a `user_id` column?

Comment: Why aren't you looking at `mysql_error`?

Comment: You are using [an **obsolete** database API](http://stackoverflow.com/q/12859942/19068) and should use a [modern replacement](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You really shouldn't be using a numerical value as a table name.

More information about that can be found in the [MySQL Documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/identifiers.html)

If you do need to use numerical table names then you'll have to use an identifier quote. Regardless, I'd recommend based on your current example to create a table called `user_1`, where 1 is the ID of that user.

This still isn't a proper solution. The comment that Mark Baker gave you is a much better idea and way of doing things.

It should also be pointed out that `mysql_*` functions are depreciated now and it's highly recommended that you stop using them. Check out the [MySQLi Functions](http://php.net/mysqli) that PHP has to offer or find another `PDO` style function.